# error: C2259: 'cv::MSER' : Cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: qt, opencv

*I am getting following error while using openCV3.1.0 in Qt. I am trying to find most stable region of the image. Img is a channels separated image, src is my source image.*

error: C2259: 'cv::MSER' : cannot instantiate abstract class due to following members:

'void cv::MSER::detectRegions(cv::InputArray,std::vector<_Ty> &,std::vector &)' : is abstract with

[ Ty=std::vector<<'cv::Point>> ]

```
   void hello(Mat& Img , Mat& src)
        {
          vector< vector< Point> > contours;
          Ptr<MSER> mser;
          vector<Rect> Boxes;
          MSER(5,10,120,0.1,.2,50,1.01,0.003,5)(Img,contours);

         for(int  i = 0 ; i  < contours.size() ; i++)
         boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours[i]) );

         for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
         {
            float width_heightRatio = (float)(boundRect[i].width/float(boundRect[i].height) );

            if( width_heightRatio < 1)
            {
              Mat Image = rectangle(src,boundRect[i],Scalar(0,0,255));
              cvNamedWindow("Test");
              imshow("Test",Image); 
              cvWaitKey(10);
            }

         }
}
```

Comment: There's a number of things wrong with your use of `MSER`, maybe have a look in the OpenCV sources for an example of how to instantiate and use the detector. For example, look at `\sources\modules\features2d\test\test_mser.cpp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create MSER after declaring like:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::MSER> mser = cv::MSER::create(5,10,120,0.1,.2,50,1.01,0.003,5);
```